# Mongoose Pre-Save Hook is Firing, but Not Saving Additional Field (NOT using model.update)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to implement a counter in my schema to grab the next issue number.    I have implemented it as a hook pre-save hook in Mongoose, and everything looks fine... with the exception the actual 'number' field does not update.   I can easily tell the hook is firing off by what gets logged to the console, even the field seems to get assigned.   But alas, no matter what I try, the 'number' field does not end up in the results.

I have seen a couple issues related to Mongoose hooks, but they all seem to be related to findOneAndUpdate or the like, which I am not using.

**Here is my full model with the hooks at the bottom:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Project = require('./projects.js');

var IssueSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true, trim: true,  index: true},
    number: {type: Number},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    vote_up: {type: Number, default: 0},
    vote_down: {type: Number, default: 0},
    comments: [new Schema({
      _id: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users'},
      description : {type: String},
      likes: {type: Number},
      date: {type: Date}
    })],
    attachments: [],
    fields: [new Schema({
      _id: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'fields'},
      value : {type: String}
    })],
    project: {type: Schema.ObjectId, required: true, index: true, ref: 'projects'},
    tags: {type: [Schema.ObjectId], required: false, default: ['56a2a0b1ea805d403f6d014b']},
    isResolved: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    created_by: {type: Schema.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'users'},
    updated_by: {type: Schema.ObjectId, required: false, ref: 'users'},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

IssueSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if(!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now;
    }
    next();
})
.pre('save', function(next) {
  Project.findOne({_id: this.project}).select('numberSeq').exec(function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('pre-save hook firing');
      this.number = doc.numberSeq;
      console.log(this.number);
      next();
    });
})
.post('save', function(doc) {
  Project.update({_id: doc.project}, {$inc:  {numberSeq: 1}}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Updated next number in seq for '  + doc.project);
  });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('issues', IssueSchema);
```

And the route to insert the issue (I am guessing this isn't where the issue is)

```
app.post('/api/issue/create', function(req, res) {

    var issue = new Issues({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      fields: req.body.fields,
      attachments: req.body.attachments,
      project: req.body.project,
      created_by: req.user || req.body.created_by,
    });

    issue.save(function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(409).send({message: 'There was an error creating the issue: ' + err});
      }
      if (!result.number) {
        console.log('number = :(');
      }
      console.log(result);
      res.send({message: 'New issue created', result: result});
    });
  });
```

[image: Screenshot of result from console with logging]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing out on the `this` context here,

```
.pre('save', function(next) {
  Project.findOne({_id: this.project}).select('numberSeq').exec(function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('pre-save hook firing');
      this.number = doc.numberSeq;
      console.log(this.number);
      next();
    });
})
```

where you say:

```
this.number = doc.numberSeq;
console.log(this.number);
```

actually refers to the callback function of the findOne query, thus you are ending up with the right console.log and wrong data inserted.

you can remember this context of the pre save hook, and later update the number using that context inside the callback. like below:

```
.pre('save', function(next) {
  var tat=this;
  Project.findOne({_id: this.project}).select('numberSeq').exec(function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('pre-save hook firing');
      tat.number = doc.numberSeq;
      console.log(tat.number);
      next();
    });
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.   I should have known that one!