# Mongoose pre-save hook fires, but does not persist data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am encountering a problem where my Mongoose pre.save() hook is firing, but the attribute does not get saved to the database. I have been searching for a long time without finding an answer.I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959817/mongoose-pre-save-hook-is-firing-but-not-saving-additional-field-not-using-mod), and the behaviour I am experiencing is very similiar, but OP's problem is related to the context of `this`, whereas I seem to have a different problem.

Here is my models.js:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const slugify = require("slugify");

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    author: String,
    post: {
        type: String,
        required: true    
    }
});

BlogPostSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.slug = slugify(this.title);
    console.log(this.slug);
    next();
});

// Passed to templates to generate url with slug.
BlogPostSchema.virtual("url").get(function() {
    console.log(this.slug);
    console.log(this.id);
    return this.slug + "/" + this.id;
});

BlogPostSchema.set("toObject", {getters: true});

let BlogPost = mongoose.model("BlogPost", BlogPostSchema);

module.exports.BlogPost = BlogPost;
```

And here is the relevant lines in the router file index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const BlogPost = require("../models").BlogPost;

// Route for accepting new blog post
router.post("/new-blog-post", (req, res, next) => {
    let blogPost = new BlogPost(req.body);
    blogPost.save((err, blogPost) => {
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.status(201);
        res.json(blogPost);
    });
});
```

I am able to save the blog post to the database, and my `console.log`'s correctly prints out the slug to the console. However, the `this.slug` in the pre-save hook does not get persisted in the database.

Can anybody see what the problem is here? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose will act according to the schema you defined.
Currently, your schema does not contain s filed named `slug`.

**You should add a `slug` field to your schema.**

Changing your current schema to something like this should work:

```
let BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
    slug: String,    
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    author: String,
    post: {
        type: String,
        required: true    
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the issue - I was expecting it to be possible to append attributes like I would a normal JS object.