# Document must have an _id before saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know this is an error that has been asked about several times on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. I have a simple schema that stores an _id and a URL. The URL works fine, but when I go to create a new schema and save it, it states the above error even though I have prehooks to explicitly define the _id.

Here's the Schema code as well as the prehook:

```js
const LinkSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: Number },
    url: { type: String, required: true }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    collection: 'links'
});

LinkSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    // Before saving, increment the count in the linkEntryCount document in the counter collection and create the doc if not already made.
    CounterModel.findByIdAndUpdate('linkEntryCount', { $inc: { count: 1 } }, { new: true, upsert: true, useFindAndModify: false }, function(err, counter) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        this._id = counter.count; // Create the previously undefined ObjectID with the +1'ed counter from linkEntryCount
        next();
    })
});
```

I've created an incrementing integer counter as per [the MongoDB database](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) - using a separate collection for counting. I've tested this and it works fine, and it even seems to assign the _id when the prehook is called. When I create an instance of the model and insert the URL, that's when the error appears. The document isn't even created.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) is there documentation on `_id` this is an internal id used by mongodb itself. You certainly can leverage it in your application but if you want to track using a separate numbered identifier, you will need to create one alongside `_id` and it can be name `id` just without the underscore

Comment: @RisingSun I got it to work using the _id method and setting the _id to a number, see my answer to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my question using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34960608/8067770).

The problem was that `this` was being used in the wrong context inside the `CounterModel.findByIdAndUpdate()` function. The code was trying to update a nonexistent field in the `linkEntryCount` collection.

Here's the fixed prehook:

```js
LinkSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var link = this;
    // Before saving, increment the count in the linkEntryCount document in the counter collection and create the doc if not already made.
    CounterModel.findByIdAndUpdate('linkEntryCount', { $inc: { count: 1 } }, { new: true, upsert: true, useFindAndModify: false }, function(err, counter) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        link._id = counter.count; // Create the previously undefined ObjectID with the +1'ed counter from linkEntryCount
        next();
    });
});
```

All I did was set the prehooks reference to `this` to a variable and then used that later in the `findByIdAndUpdate()` function.

Comment: you shouldnt do that

Answer (score 2):

```
 _id: { type: Number },
```

A mongodb _id isnt a number but a  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId

So replace that line with

```
 _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
```

You should use _id only with

```
new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
```

And then you can add like id: { type: Number } and use that as the counter

Comment: The MongoDB docs describe the _id field as "_id must be unique, and always has an index with a unique constraint. However, except for the unique constraint you can use any value for the _id field in your collections." So, I should be able to have any type for the _id field as long as it's unique, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, try it out and keep me updated!

Comment: Hey, I got the _id method to work; see my answer to this question. The _id of the document does in fact work as a number.